# How to Get the Name of Current Layout of a CMS Page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

Under the design tab of a CMS page in Magento's admin area, there is the option to specify a page layout.
I have a few custom fields that I wish to display only on certain page layouts.
How can I grab the name of the page layout so I can proceed with an if statement for displaying my custom fields?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I discovered the answer to my question after some more Google searching and found this site: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/309190/.
The following code snippet will give you the name of the current page layout:
    `$layout = Mage::registry('cms_page')->getRootTemplate();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$root = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('root');

if ($root) 
{
    $rootTemplate = $root->getTemplate(); 

    switch ($rootTemplate ) 
    {
        case 'page/2column.phtml':
            // Do something.
            break;

        //etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on finding your solution, but this may help you out moving forward:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html

I find it useful at times.